# Why does MSVC not implement function 'sprintf_s' like function 'asprintf' in MSVC 2005?

Tags: c, cl.exe

In compilers on Unix-based OSes and MinGW/MSYS2 on Windows, function `asprintf` is the version of function `sprintf` with security enhancements. That is because `asprintf` allocates the buffer with sufficient size for the string.

```
char *str = NULL;
asprintf (&str, "%s", "hello, world");
...
free (str);
```

However, Microsoft does not implement this function in MSVC. Instead, Microsoft implements `sprintf_s` from MSVC 2005. Unlike `asprintf`, `sprintf_s` does not allocate the buffer with sufficient size for the string. It requires an extra argument for buffer size:

```
char *str = (char *)calloc (100, sizeof (char));
sprintf_s (str, 100, "%s", "hello, world");
...
free (str);
```

The purpose of these two functions is to avoid buffer overflow. But `asprintf` can completely avoid buffer overflow, while `sprintf_s` cannot. If someone uses a large integer for the buffer size argument in function `sprintf_s`, buffer overflow can still happen. For example:

```
char *str1 = (char [100]){""}, *str2 = (char [100]){""};
...
sprintf_s (str1, 200, "%s\n%s", str2, "hello, world");
...
```

---

Similarly, `scanf` family functions in compilers on Unix-based OSes and MinGW/MSYS2 on Windows support the `m` specifier for security enhancements:

```
char *str = NULL;
scanf ("%m[^\n]", &str);
...
free (str);
```

But MSVC implements `scanf_s` family functions requiring an extra argument for buffer size:

```
char *str = (char *)calloc (100, sizeof (char));
scanf_s ("%[^\n]", str, 100);
...
free (str);
```

Actually, the `m` specifier can completely avoid buffer overflow, but function `scanf_s` in MSVC cannot. For example:

```
char *str = (char *)calloc (100, sizeof (char));
scanf_s ("%[^\n]", str, 200);
...
free (str);
```

---

So why does Microsoft not choose to use dynamic allocation of the buffer with sufficient size for input string to avoid buffer overflow, but using an extra argument for buffer size instead in MSVC from MSVC 2005? (The former method can completely avoid buffer overflow, but the latter one cannot)

NB: `_s` functions are NOT in C standard until C11. Microsoft started to implement them from MSVC 2005.

Comment: "Unix-based OSes and MinGW/MSYS2 on Windows" that is basically the answer. Windows is not UNIX based. And you wouldn't need such a thing like MinGW if it was. Also the manpage for [asprintfg](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) tells us: "These functions are GNU extensions, not in C or POSIX."

Comment: @Gerhardh Well, OP is incorrect in that [all] "Unix-based OSes" would include `asprintf`. Only those using the GNU C Standard Library do.

Comment: If you really want to know why they decided to do it that way, that would not be answerable without asking them. Or it would just be opinionated.

Comment: @AKX that may be true but does it matter? If Windows is ot a "UNIX based system" it also is "not a UNIX-based system using GNU C standard lib"

Comment: @Gerhardh For accuracy. You wouldn't necessarily have `asprintf` on HP-UX, IRIX, what-have-you, either, or when using an alternate libc on an otherwise GNU system. (I think it's important for OP to understand the separation between a C compiler and the C standard library it might use.)

Comment: @AKX again, how is that relevant for the question why VS does not provide it and my comment that Windows is neither of them? The more you narrow down the range of OSes the more correct my comment gets that Windows doesn't belong to that group. In case you want to make the OP aware of that detail, you might address them instead of me.

Comment: Consider implementing it: https://modelingwithdata.org/pdfs/174-asprintf.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Quoth [the docs for `asprintf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html), emphasis mine:

> CONFORMING TO:
>
> **These functions are GNU extensions, not in C or POSIX.**  They are
> also available under *BSD.  The FreeBSD implementation sets strp
> to NULL on error.

IOW, because MSVC isn't GNU, and doesn't implement that GNU extension to the C standard library.

MingW/MSYS use the GNU C Standard Library, which does implement the function.

Answer (score 0):

`sprintf_s()` is in the C standard optional Annex K.

`asprintf()` is not in the C spec.

Implementing `asprintf()` is not needed to make a compliant C compiler/library.

---

MSVC implements `sprintf_s()`, yet not properly with the type of the size parameter.

Comment: `sprintf_s` is implemented in 2005 and higher version of MSVC, but not until 2011 is it in Annex K

Comment: @stanchcorder6 And as so often, not properly. I would avoid using MSVC, any version.